# sql get students names who passed in all subjects

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have 3 tables

students(id,name)

subjects(id,name)

student_subjects(student_id,subject_id,mark)

I want to select student names who passed all subjects (who have mark>=50 in all subjects)

I tried this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.NAME
FROM STUDENT_SUBJECTS sb,
  STUDENTS s,
  SUBJECTS b
WHERE s.ID   = sb.STUDENT_ID
AND b.ID     = sb.SUBJECT_ID
AND sb.MARK >= 50
```

but this get students who have any subject that is bigger than or equal to 50
is there any way to get just the names of students who passed all subjects?
[image: oracle schema]

Comment: Post a working test case. That should include create, insert statements along with your desired output. Nobody can reproduce your issue just by looking at the question.

Comment: It's a good idea to do the assignments without too much help, if you want to pass. If you want just the student names, NOT EXISTS may help.

Comment: SQL Fiddle appears to be down, but.. you want to count subject and student_subhects rows grouped by student

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should works:

```
SELECT s.NAME
FROM STUDENT_SUBJECTS sb,
  STUDENTS s,
  SUBJECTS b
WHERE s.ID   = sb.STUDENT_ID
AND b.ID     = sb.SUBJECT_ID
GROUP BY S.NAME
HAVING MIN(SB.MARK)>=50
```

In case exists two students with same name just group by id also:

```
SELECT s.NAME
FROM STUDENT_SUBJECTS sb,
  STUDENTS s,
  SUBJECTS b
WHERE s.ID   = sb.STUDENT_ID
AND b.ID     = sb.SUBJECT_ID
GROUP BY S.ID,S.NAME
HAVING MIN(SB.MARK)>=50
```